# A confusion caused by a grammar checker regarding "a" or "an"

Tags: numbers, indefinite-articles

I wrote it this way in my manuscript:

> We construct a 25-order  planar graph  with  minimum degree 4.

My grammar checker (languagetool.jar) is reminding me to use "an" instead of "a." I'm a bit unsure, so I'm asking here.
[image]

I suspect the reason could be that the grammar checker doesn't recognize "25" and instead directly recognizes "order."

I'm not sure if the issue is with this software or if it's related to using "number-noun" constructions (as there might be specific rules regarding this).

Comment: Whether to use "a" or "an" will depend on how you pronounce "25".  If you say "twenty-five", then use "a".  Maybe languagetool had in mind some other pronunciation...

Comment: @GEdgar is there a different way of pronouncing "25"?

Comment: Amazingly I have found examples on Amazon and other suppliers which use the indefinite article "Designed with **an 22 mm closed top** with no septa for non-critical analysis" and "Portraits are often mentioned as a problem for **an 28 mm lens perspective**."  Who knew!? BUT the vast majority of results show a preference for the indefinite article "a"

Comment: @AndrewLeach This question is closed as a duplicate of two older questions but the number *1100* does indeed have two different pronunciations: "one thousand (and) one hundred" OR "**Eleven** hundred". What other way can **25-order** be pronounced?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question is answered by the first duplicate. The second is tangentially relevant. If you think it should be removed, raise a flag and another mod will consider it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach so are you confirming that there is only one way to pronounce "25-order"?

Comment: Well, I suppose 25 could be spelled out in digits. I reiterate: please raise a flag.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Whether said as "twenty-five" or as "two-five" or as "twenty-fifth" or any other permutation, the initial "t" does not change, nor should the "a" be changed to an "an."  This is _not_ an initial vowel that could change depending on its pronunciation, nor is it an "h" or any other letter that might be silent.

Comment: Using 'an' here is wrong, plain and simple. The choice is determined by pronunciation of the following entity alone (with one or two grey areas with words like _hotel_ / _historic_, and where what follows is open to differing pronunciations  (eg FAQ) or even readings).